# Toggle keyboard in iOS using Javascript

Tags: javascript, ios4, keyboard, toggle

For **iOS**, instead of showing the keyboard any time you click inside a textbox, can I create a button to **toggle the keyboard** on and off so users can have control over when to display the keyboard? What's the javascript function for it?

PLease note I want to do it in **javascript** not objective-C.

Thanks,

Comment: what part of the default behavior (showing the keyboard when the user clicks an input field) you don't like?

Comment: I don't know about chepukha, but I don't like the way that it doesn't show the keyboard when you're in a contenteditable div.  The android webkit based browser does.  Beyond that, you might want to be able to create/use shortcut keys.

Comment: Thanks for responding guys. I actually want a keyboard to input math equation. Therefore, I need a lot greek symbols and some other math symbols. I decided to create another keyboard for that purpose and pop up the default keyboard only when needed to input text. I've checked PhoneGap library but didn't find any function to control keyboard. Any suggestion?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@George: I finally decided that I don't need the regular textbox because I have a customized keyboard anyway. That way I won't have to worry about the keyboard popping up when touching my 'customized' textfield.

Anyway, thanks for your effort.

Comment: So the answer is don't use a text input.  Awesome.

Answer (score 2):

I'm fairly certain there isn't a dedicated JavaScript method for controlling the keyboard, but you might be able to fake it with jQuery.  Assuming you have a text input like this:

```
<input type="text" name="formula"/>
```

Your JavaScript code would look something like:

```
$(function(){           

    $("#formula").focus(function(){

        $(this).blur();

        /* 
         Put code here to bring up your custom keyboard. Update 
         the value of #forumla as symbols are pressed.
        */

    });

});
```

If you want to add a button to your custom keyboard that brings up the traditional keyboard you would want it to execute:

```
$("#formula").focus();
```

Lastly, if you only want the keyboard that pops up to default to the numbers keyboard, which sounds like it could be a nice added touch for you, you can tell iOS the element is for numbers number by changing your element to look like this:

```
<input type="number" id="formula"/>
```

You should be able to accomplish what you're trying to do with these tips.

Comment: thanks George. I'm not close to my comp now, but will give it a try tomorrow.

Comment: I think it's a nice trick. However, it has a side effect that the keyboard will still try to show, but then will be hiden by calling blur(). There will be a short moment that the keyboard pop up and down which still looks bad. I will keep this topic open for a while and if no one else answer to it then I will accept your answer. I have voted it up though.